# How to create live usb with persistent partition for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb

I read that due to an error at casper scripts, Ubuntu 15.10+ assumes at boot time that the first partition is the persistence partition and the second one is the root.

So this drops you to initramfs shell before boot if you try to follow the guides, creating a second partition with casper-rw label and delete casper-rw file due to file-size constraints of FAT32.

My question is, how can I create a persistence partition on the usb-stick (which is pretty fast) and boot Ubuntu 16.04 without dropped to initramfs shell?

Comment: Have you tried the built-in Startup Disk Creator program?

Comment: Funny thing is that I have suffered exactly from this issue three weeks ago (not to mention I deleted my host Ubuntu OS). It was disastrous. Anyhow, try UNetBootIn with persistent option (Don't forget to tick the box).

Comment: mkusb works with all current Ubuntu versions and flavours. See the links in the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can try mkusb. It is made to work with all current Ubuntu versions and flavours. It will create a casper-rw partition automatically.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

[mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)